# Spring Boot XML Header and Version Tag

Tags: xml, spring-boot

I am returning text/xml responses in my spring boot application. However, there are two key issues that cannot be recoverable on the client side (since we are not authorized to make any change on the client):

1 - The first issue is: My responses do not include

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

.

How can I add this ?

2 - The second one is: Content-Length header is missing in my responses. How can I include this ?

Thank you for your valuable ideas.